# How to Edit txt file content using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to store users comments of my site, in a txt file.
so.. i want to know how to edit txt file content using php.

my txt file contents goes like this...

```
uid=5
comment="Hello world"
time="2013:11:21:xx:xx"

uid=6
comment="Test comment"
time="2013:11:21:xx:xx"
```

so..if i want to edit uid=5's comment, how can i do it with php.
or tell me a better method, content should go in text file to make this task eazy.

i dont like to use databse to store my comments.
pls, someone help me in this matter.
Thansk

Comment: You're FAR better off using a DB. You'll have a "whale of a time" with what you're trying to achieve. Take the iniative and use a DB, I did and it's the best decision I ever made. You'll be going through **EDIT HELL** coding, till the "cows come home".

Comment: A better method would be with a database...you'd save an incredible amount of text parsing with a database. At worst you could possibly use JSON objects stored in a text file, but even then you'll have headaches.

Comment: You should use CSV files for this functionality

Comment: What's your objection to using a database to store comments? technically, your .txt file is a database.. just a very poor one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$txt_file = file_get_contents('path/to/file');
$rows = explode("\n", $txt_file); //you get all rows here
foreach ($rows as $row => &$data) {
    if (strstr($data, 'uid=5') !== FALSE) {
        //it means the following line contains your comment, 
        //work with it as string
        $rows[$row + 1] = "comment=" . $newComment;
    }
    $data = $data . "\n";
}
file_put_contents('path/to/file', $rows);
```

Comment: Thansk you, this is simple and working. i am going to crate site that allo users to make post and comments. there i going to add posts in databse and store comments in txt file, and i put a link to txt file in table row which relevant to the post. 
i do this way i fell that will MySQL databases speed enough to serve form within thousends of rows? what do you think is this a good idea ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question, but MySQL database can very quickly process millions of rows. If you're just starting your website I don't think you should worry about database performance. You can start thinking about the performance when your site starts to grow.

Answer (score 1):

json offers a simple way to serialize an array to a string.
using [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you can convert your example above to have one json record per row.

then use the answer above to read one line at a time and look for the uid you have in mind.  just json_decode the row to get entire array for the comment.

this method allows you to change the number of attributes on your comments later and/or make some of the attributes optional without making the file parsing complex, or relying on double blank links or white space tricks to separate records.

file example

```
{ 'uid':'5','comment'='Hello world','time'='2013:11:21:xx:xx' }\r\n
{ 'uid':'6','comment'='Hello world','time'='2013:11:21:xx:xx' }\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a database server available, I suggest you use [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php). It acts like a real database server, but it stores it's data in a file on disk. By using just a regular text file you're going to end up in trouble sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bhavik Shah, if you can't use a database then a csv would be easier to work with. However assuming you can't do either of those below is a solution, not the most elegant, but a solution none the less.

```
$file = 'myfile.txt';
$fileArray = file( $file );
$reachedUser = false;
for( $i=0; $i<=count($fileArray); $i++ ){
    if( preg_match('/uid=6/', $fileArray[$i] ) == 1 ){
        $reachedUser = true;
        continue;
    }
    if( $reachedUser && preg_match('/comment=/', $fileArray[$i]) ){
        $fileArray[$i] = "comment=\"This is the users new comment\"\n";
        break;
    }
}
reset( $fileArray );

$fh = fopen( $file, "w" );
foreach( $fileArray as $line ){
    fwrite( $fh, $line );
}
```

Comment: morgunder's solution is much easier. Convert your text document into a json document. Then play with it with json_decode.